# 'Not defined' error with Masonry javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, typeerror, referenceerror

I am using [Vanilla Masonry](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html) (the raw JS, non-jQuery version) as follows:

In head:

```
<script id="masonry" type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/masonry.js"></script>
```

In body:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var wall = new Masonry( document.getElementById('ext-component-3'), {
    columnWidth: 145
  });
};
</script>
```

But I keep getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Masonry is not defined 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong in my setup?

Comment: How about a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at the masonry.js code.

You need to move the reference to the masonry file to the bottom of your page (before the closing body tag).

Or at least beneath the opening body tag.

Its trying to appendChild to the body tag which hasn't loaded in the head section.

Comment: on Network tab I see it is loading correctly - interestingly, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined` even if I only load `masonry.js`, *without* the script in the body

Comment: Updated my answer. give that a shot!

Comment: its better to put all your javascript references at the bottom of the page anyway. faster load times (so long as anything needed there isn't be used prior to page load).