# ReferenceError: Masonry is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a simple page with Masonry.
I **don't** want to use jQuery, and according to the official website (http://masonry.desandro.com/) it's possible.

I'm using the "masonry.pkgd.js for development". Here is my code lines, juste before `</body>` (according to ['Not defined' error with Masonry javascript plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738564/not-defined-error-with-masonry-javascript-plugin?rq=1)) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<script>
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.item'
});
</script>
```

But firefox / chrome gives me `"ReferenceError: Masonry is not defined"` at the line of `"new Masonry(..."`. There is no 404 error on the inclusion of "masonry.pkgd.js".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was a bug in masonry.pkgd.min.js - David updated it at http://masonry.desandro.com

Comment: Hello, thanks, i saw your twitter message. But I was using the dev version (without bug). anyway, I tried the new one, same result. I updated my post with a test link.

Comment: Ok, got it worked. Something is really wrong with the website's JS... I did 3-4wget of the same masonry.pkgd.js, one of the files is working... it's all i did.